# Access spark-shell from different Spark versions

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, cloudera-cdh, apache-spark-standalone

**TL;DR**: Is it absolutely necessary that the Spark running a spark-shell (driver) have the **exactly same version** of the Spark's master?

I am using **Spark 1.5.0** to connect to **Spark 1.5.0-cdh5.5.0** via spark-shell:

```
spark-shell --master spark://quickstart.cloudera:7077 --conf "spark.executor.memory=256m"
```

It connects, instantiates the SparkContext and sqlContext fine. If I run:

```
sqlContext.sql("show tables").show()
```

it shows all my tables as expected.

However, if I try to access data from a table:

```
sqlContext.sql("select * from t1").show()
```

I get this error:

```
java.io.InvalidClassException: org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.AttributeReference; local class incompatible: stream classdesc serialVersionUID = 370695178000872136, local class serialVersionUID = -8877631944444173448
```

[Full stacktrace](http://pastebin.com/8weHE9Lj)

It says that the *serialVersionUIDs* don't match. My hypothesis is that the problem is caused by trying to connect two different versions of spark. Any ideas if I'm right?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are absolutely right.

In your spark shell, you try to deserialize a serialized object from you workers (cluster). As the versions of those classes are different, you get the `java.io.InvalidClassException`.

Try to use same spark versions and it will be fine.